# Give me an example to generate barcode in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, barcode

I'm just new here and I know that this site will surely help me out with my concerns,a friend told me.
Well, I'm having a hard time to create a program on how generate a barcode using Java.
I need to generate unique barcode for books.
What I want to happen is that, I want to generate a barcode with an intended Book_Id, the Book_Id will be inputted by the user and when the button is click, it will generate a barcode with a corresponding Book_Id.

Please help me out of this,I really need your help sirs.

Comment: Hello Newbie, welcome at stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode

Comment: **Jon Mark Perry**, can you give an example on how to do it on Java?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to use an existing tool for this. Here are some options:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/barbecue/
- http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Here is an example of how to use the Barbeque API: https://github.com/cloudsoft/barbecue/blob/master/src/zip/examples/ExampleCode128.java

Comment: Am I just going to paste this to my  generate **button**?

Comment: Here is a more straightforward example: http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/barcodes/barbecue/barcode-size.html    Pass your book ID into the createCode128B() function.

Comment: Sir, what is this **test-size.png** here? what's that for?

Comment: That is to save a png image of the bar code. You could call this something like: `"book" + Book_Id + ".png"`

Comment: Sir how about where to get the **barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar**?

Comment: Sir I got an error when I pass my book_Id textfield in the Code128B()Function. Here's my code sir **Barcode barcodes = BarcodeFactory.createCode128B(res.getText())//error here;
    barcodes.setBarHeight(60);
    barcodes.setBarWidth(2);** error says, **unreported exception BarcodeException;must be caught or declared to be thrown**

Comment: You need to catch or throw the exception as it is a checked exception. To do this, surround the code in your comment with a try block i.e. `try {` before your code and `} catch(BarcodeException){ // do something here, exception was thrown }` after it. If we reach the catch block at runtime which contains my comment to do something, this means an exception was thrown and the Barbecue library failed to create the bar code for some reason. Therefore you can do something in the catch block like logging or displaying an error saying that the barcode generation failed.

Comment: Sir, there's nor error left however, the barcode that is being generated was not found. I want to set display the barcode in the label but when I set it, the number I inputted in the textfield is the one that display in the label, instead of barcodes. How to do this sir?

Comment: I don't think you can set the number which will be displayed on the barcode as the barcode number will be generated by the library.

Comment: If you want to post your code that creates the barcode, I can take a look at it.

Comment: sir,would you mind if I'll ask your email address? so that I can PM you when I  have something to ask from you? Is that ok with you sir?

Comment: If you would like a fast answer to your questions in the future, I would recommend asking them on StackOverflow instead of emailing me directly :) If you cannot get an answer to a Java question which is highly unlikely, you can respond to this thread and I will get a notification and take a look at your question.

Comment: sir, I have another question, please see this link **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843106/how-to-generate-multiple-barcodes-in-java**

Answer (score 0):

Download the library JAR File - ConnectCodeBarcodeFontLibrary.jar

Add the jar file into java project.
Import library in source code:

```
import net.connectcode.*;
```

Make a `jLabel1` on form and type the following code:

```
public void generateBarCode()
{
    Code39 code39=new Code39();
    String outputStr=code39.encode("12345678", 1);
    //String humanTextStr=code39.getHumanText();
    jLabel1.setText(outputStr);
    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("CCode39_S3_Trial",java.awt.Font.PLAIN,24));
}
```