# How to generate multiple barcodes in java?

Tags: java, netbeans, barcode

I have a window form and I have a textField1(book_id), textField2(number of copies) and a generate button. Now, I want to generate barcodes based on the number of copies inputted by the user, and the book_id inputted by the user will also increment.

**Example: I inputted 2000 in the book_id and the number of copies is 2, so when I click generate button it will give me 2 barcodes with a book_id of 2000 for the first barcode and 2001 for the second barcode.**

I'm hoping to hearing from you.

Comment: Could you show the code that you have written to attempt the solution?

Comment: Sir, just forget about this. Can you help me with this one instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866779/how-to-delete-specific-file-from-folder-in-java-without-deleting-the-folder-its

Comment: I would not have anything to add to the answer that is already there. As already said by another user, you need to check the value of File's delete() function.

Comment: sir, do you have an idea on how to generate multiple barcodes?

Comment: Once you have created one barcode using `BarcodeFactory.createCode128B()`, you can create multiple barcodes by repeating the same code e.g. create the barcode, create the file and save the image as seen here: http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/barcodes/barbecue/barcode-size.html

Answer (score 0):

Is just a font type you don't need to generate it.
If you want to print an id as barcode  you just need to select the barcode font type Name in your document before print
Look up in google for some barcode

Comment: how to do that sir? can you give example?