# How to delete specific file from folder in JAVA, without deleting the folder itself?

Tags: java

I'm having a problem in deleting a specific file in a folder, 
This is what I want to happen:

**I want to delete a file, having the file name of..**

This is my code by the way:

```
try
{
    File f=new File("C://Generated Barcodes//"+file_copy.getText()+".png");//full path like c:/home/ri
    if(!f.exists())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something Went Wrong!",
        " ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else
    {
        f.delete();
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

can anyone help me out on how to do it.? It did not delete the file actually.
And I guess, the **delete()** there, doesn't do anything.
Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What did delete return?

Comment: What exception, if any, did you catch? Post your stack trace. Also, are you sure you should be using forward slashes like that?

Comment: Sir immibis, it returned the JOptionPane **Something Went Wrong**

Comment: I believe the deletion needs to be assigned to a Boolean.

Comment: **Sir MarsAtcomic**, actually it did not return the stack trace, instead it return the message **Something Went Wrong**

Comment: How to do it **Sir Malik Brahimi**?, could you provide example sir?

Comment: if `Something Went Wrong` is displayed the problem is not the delete, but the exists. Check the path to be correct.

Comment: you must be soore that the file isn't already opened to another Application or your app(It will not be deleted!).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you check for existence? Just try deleting, and catch with the alert. Put the error message in the catch.

```
try
{
    File f=new File("C:/Generated Barcodes/" + file_copy.getText() + ".png");
    boolean deleted = f.delete();
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something Went Wrong!",
        " ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Just single slash? not double slash? Here's the example path that's being retrieved: **C:\Generated Barcodes\Fiilipino_884.png**

Comment: @Newbie Try the code now, it should be fully functional.